# Aiogram Webhook Local TelegramBotAPI server

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

My Code

```
TOKEN = config['TOKEN']

# Webserver settings
# bind localhost only to prevent any external access
WEB_SERVER_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
# Port for incoming request from reverse proxy. Should be any available port
WEB_SERVER_PORT = 8443

# Path to webhook route, on which Telegram will send requests
WEBHOOK_PATH = f'/webhook/{TOKEN}'
# Base URL for webhook will be used to generate webhook URL for Telegram,
# in this example it is used public DNS with HTTPS support
BASE_WEBHOOK_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/"

# All handlers should be attached to the Router (or Dispatcher)
router = Router()


@router.message(CommandStart())
async def command_start_handler(message: Message) -> None:
    """
    This handler receives messages with `/start` command
    """
    # Most event objects have aliases for API methods that can be called in events' context
    # For example if you want to answer to incoming message you can use `message.answer(...)` alias
    # and the target chat will be passed to :ref:`aiogram.methods.send_message.SendMessage`
    # method automatically or call API method directly via
    # Bot instance: `bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, ...)`
    await message.answer(f"Hello, {hbold(message.from_user.full_name)}!")


@router.message()
async def echo_handler(message: types.Message) -> None:
    """
    Handler will forward receive a message back to the sender

    By default, message handler will handle all message types (like text, photo, sticker etc.)
    """
    try:
        # Send a copy of the received message
        await message.send_copy(chat_id=message.chat.id)
    except TypeError:
        # But not all the types is supported to be copied so need to handle it
        await message.answer("Nice try!")


async def on_startup(bot: Bot) -> None:
    # If you have a self-signed SSL certificate, then you will need to send a public
    # certificate to Telegram
    await bot.set_webhook(f"{BASE_WEBHOOK_URL}{WEBHOOK_PATH}")

async def on_shutdown(bot: Bot) -> None:
    await bot.delete_webhook()

def main() -> None:
    # Dispatcher is a root router
    dp = Dispatcher()
    # ... and all other routers should be attached to Dispatcher
    dp.include_router(router)

    # Register startup hook to initialize webhook
    dp.startup.register(on_startup)
    dp.shutdown.register(on_shutdown)
    session = AiohttpSession(
        api=TelegramAPIServer.from_base('http://localhost:8081')
    )
    # Initialize Bot instance with a default parse mode which will be passed to all API calls
    bot = Bot(TOKEN, session=session)
    logging.info(bot.get_me())
    # Create aiohttp.web.Application instance
    app = web.Application()

    # Create an instance of request handler,
    # aiogram has few implementations for different cases of usage
    # In this example we use SimpleRequestHandler which is designed to handle simple cases
    webhook_requests_handler = SimpleRequestHandler(
        dispatcher=dp,
        bot=bot,
        secret_token=WEBHOOK_SECRET,
    )
    # Register webhook handler on application
    webhook_requests_handler.register(app, path=WEBHOOK_PATH)

    # Mount dispatcher startup and shutdown hooks to aiohttp application
    setup_application(app, dp, bot=bot)

    # And finally start webserver
    web.run_app(app, host=WEB_SERVER_HOST, port=WEB_SERVER_PORT)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        handlers=[RotatingFileHandler(
                        filename="logs/logs.txt", maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=5, encoding="utf-8")],
                        format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s", encoding="utf-8", datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    main()
```

The telegram server is running locally, it works, when you just connect to it everything works, but when you try to start it like this it doesn’t react at all, and there are no errors in the logs, what could be the problem?

pooling works, but when I try to start it with a webhook it doesn’t

I've already tried all sorts of options, but I still don't understand why it might not work